# How can I run GameActivity template in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, cmake, android-gameactivity

I've found GameActivity template when I create Android Project.

[image]

I ran it but

1. First of all, the minSdk must be over 29(from 30)
2. Second of all, control part source seems broken.

```
void Renderer::handleInput() {
    // handle all queued inputs
    for (auto i = 0; i < app_->motionEventsCount; i++) {

        // cache the current event
        auto &motionEvent = app_->motionEvents[i];

        // cache the current action
        auto action = motionEvent.action;

        // Find the pointer index, mask and bitshift to turn it into a readable value
        auto pointerIndex = (action & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                >> AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        aout << "Pointer " << pointerIndex << ":";

        // get the x and y position of this event
        auto &pointer = motionEvent.pointers[pointerIndex];
        auto x = GameActivityPointerAxes_getX(&pointer);
        auto y = GameActivityPointerAxes_getY(&pointer);
        aout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ") ";

        // Only consider touchscreen events, like touches
        auto actionMasked = action & AINPUT_SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN;

        // determine the kind of event it is
        switch (actionMasked) {
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN:
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                aout << "Pointer Down";
                break;

            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_UP:
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                aout << "Pointer Up";
                break;

            default:
                aout << "Pointer Move";
        }

        aout << std::endl;
    }

    // clear inputs, be careful as this will clear it for anyone listening to these events
    android_app_clear_motion_events(app_);
}
```

motionEventsCount, motionEvents, etc don't exist.

How can I solve this two issues?

Comment: Yeah, this one needs to be updated to the latest version: specifically the input event processing, and release build configuration.  there is an internal bug b/254342244 to track this, will update it here once it is done. In the mean time, you may try with https://github.com/ggfan/playground/tree/master/android/games/gamesdk/NativeToGameMigration, and refer to https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity (on the way of being updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is in:

- Giraffe (2022.3.1) Canary 2 and above (download from d.android.com/studio/preview)
- future Flamingo (probably 2022.2.2) releases